# Keras class weights

Tags: keras

`keras` documentation is a little vague about `class_weight` parameter in `model.fit()`. I have a dataset with binary labels but it's instances per class are imbalanced. `Class 0` has `1000` instances while `class 1` has `15,000` instances. How would I set `class_weight` dictionary in this case? Would it be like `class_weight = {0: 0.07, 1: 0.93}` or there's some other method to calculate these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the class weight to {0: 0.07, 1: 0.93} you are telling your model to make the correct classification of class: 1 15 times more important. You can think about it as you would just use the same training instance 15 times to train the model.

Comment: So to tackle the imbalance in data, I should set it to {0: 0.93, 1: 0.07}. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, you could actually also use the scikit learn class_weight calculator:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.class_weight.compute_class_weight.html